# How to add custom metrics to Keycloak 22 with Quarkus and MicroMeter

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, micrometer

The recent versions of Keycloak, at leat 22.0.1, which are based on Quarkus now provide MicroMeter metrics in Prometheus format as documented on https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration-metrics.

I would like to write an extension JAR that adds some further metrics about about e.g. number of logins to each realm based on the Keycloak `EventListenerProvider` and `RealmResourceProvider`.

I've got everything working using my own `PrometheusMeterRegistry` that is available at a custom endpoint `/auth/realms/master/custom-metrics`. Somewhat similar to https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi

The problem is, that Prometheus can only scape one URL, either the original or my custom one.

**How can I add my custom metrics to the original MeterRegistry?**

As the Keycloak metrics do not contain anything Keycloak specific, I assume they are coming from the underlying Quarkus server. So would I have to write a Quarkus extension to be able to use `@Inject MeterRegistry meterRegistry`? And combine that with `implements RealmResourceProviderFactory`? Or is there some Keycloak SPI that returns the `MeterRegistry`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure of the actual Micrometer Keycloak setup, but most likely the quarkus-micrometer extension is already there and you can see how it works here:

https://quarkus.io/guides/telemetry-micrometer#obtain-a-reference-to-a-meterregistry

Comment: Thanks, I missed the globally available `Metrics.globalRegistry`. Using just a  `api("io.quarkus:quarkus-micrometer:3.2.0.Final")` dependency it works great!